# Flutter/Dart - Split Comma Separated String into 3 Variables?

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, split, conditional-statements

I've got a comma-separated string of tags, IE "grubs, sheep, dog". How can I separate this into three variables? I tried ;

```
var splitag = tagname.split(",");
var splitag1 = splitag[0];
var splitag2 = splitag[1];
var splitag3 = splitag[2];
```

But if any of the variables are null it throws an error. So I tried;

```
String splitagone = splitag1 ?? "";
String splitagtwo = splitag2 ?? "";
String splitagthree = splitag3 ?? "";
```

But I got the same error. So is there another way I can check that the tag is not null and use the variable?

```
if(tagname != null) {
      tagname.split(',').forEach((tag) {       
      //  something?    
      });
    }
```

Comment: Also check if `tagname.isNotEmpty` and tag also

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a `Map`, which is better suited for variables with dynamic length :

```dart
final tagName = 'grubs, sheep';
final split = tagName.split(',');
final Map<int, String> values = {
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    i: split[i]
};
print(values);  // {0: grubs, 1:  sheep}

final value1 = values[0];
final value2 = values[1];
final value3 = values[2];

print(value1);  // grubs
print(value2);  //  sheep
print(value3);  // null
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use a list and add items one by one

```
final names= 'first, second';
final splitNames= names.split(',');
List splitList;
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    splitList.add(splitNames[i]);
}
```

Comment: final names= 'first, second';
final splitNames= names.split(',');
List splitList;
  for (int i = 0; i < splitNames.length; i++){
    splitList.add(splitNames[i]);
}

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the string splits before using them:

```
final names= 'first, second, 3';
values = names.split(",").map((x) => x.trim())).where((element) => element.isNotEmpty).toList()

final value1 = values[0];
final value2 = values[1];
final value3 = values[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just want to check if tagname is null just use `tagname?.split()`. But then when you get the values you will have to do this as well because otherwise you'll get a null exception `splitTag?[] ?? ""` The ?? is optional if you want to return a blank string instead of null.